# Extracting implications in polynomial constraint system from Groebner basis

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, ideals, groebner-bases

Given a Groebner basis for a system of polynomial constraints over $\mathbb{Q}$, are there any known methods for extracting the low degree factorable polynomials in the ideal generated by that basis?

I am trying to learn more about the solutions of a particular polynomial constraint system, and would like to  find low degree polynomials in the ideal that factor.  Because if $f, g$ are polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, and $fg$ is in the ideal, this can be rephrased as an implication
$$ f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \neq 0 \ \ \implies \ \ g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0 $$
which holds for all solutions of the constraint system. With a Groebner basis, if I want to check if $fg$ is in the ideal, that is straightforward. However the reverse appears difficult, and I have not found a way to automate finding $f$, $g$ such that $fg$ is in the ideal.

If I restrict to considering monomials, there is actually a subideal generated by monomials which describes all monomials in the original ideal. Furthermore there are [techniques to calculate it](https://apcocoa.uni-passau.de/wiki/index.php?title=CoCoA:MonsInIdeal).

Are all the non-trivially-factorable polynomials in an ideal similarly described by a subideal generated by non-trivially-factorable polynomials?
That would be wonderful, but I assume it is a bit much to ask for, because in the monomial ideal case, the monomials must be generated from the leading terms of the Groebner basis (by definition), and thus it does not seem too surprising that all monomials in the ideal are generated from a monomial subideal.

Are there any known techniques / algorithms, for determining the non-trivially-factorable polynomials in an ideal up to some degree $d$, given the Groebner basis for the ideal?

Do such sets of factorable polynomials have a name, or are closely related to some other questions, which could be helpful to read up on?